# PrestaShop - How to add discount for a category

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I must add a discount of 0% for two categories, the others categories must have a discount of 20%. I'm looking a way to add quickly. Maybe there is a free module?

Answer (score 4):

In admin area there is a page for your purpose.

Go to `price rules` and `Catalog Price Rules`. Press `Add new catalog price rule`.

From this panel you can decide discounts er category. In principal area select general option and in `Add a new condition group` select the category involved.